# Dropdown item method click overrides default click

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have simple dropdown with a single item and method `onItemClick()`.
Problem is that this method overrides the default method.

```
<custom-dropdown>
        <custom-menu-item (click)="onItemClick()">
        </custom-menu-item>
</custom-dropdown>
```

What I want to do is to first execute the default method and then execute my method `onItemClick()`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What default method?

Comment: Default method of custom-menu-item. Problem is when my method onItemClick() is called i assume default method overrides what i did in my method and then custom-menu-item is not doing what it should be doing.